# Undefined subroutine LWP::Protocol::https::Socket::can_read called

Tags: perl, vmware

I'm trying to script some interaction between a Linux box and an ESXi host, using the VMware Perl library (which appears to call a SOAP service on the ESXi host).

I am getting an error for which I can't find a solution: `Undefined subroutine &LWP::Protocol::https::Socket::can_read called at /usr/local/share/perl5/LWP/Protocol/http.pm line 22`

I am currently running Net-HTTP-6.03.  I did try with Net-HTTP-6.05 but it makes the web-based calls very slow (and subsequent ones also eventually fail, instead with about 1.2MB of XML as the error message) -- which various forums suggest is only resolvable by reverting to 6.03 (via `cpan install GAAS/Net-HTTP-6.03.tar.gz`).

The crux of my code is as follows:

```
use VMware::VIRuntime;
my $context = {
    options => ParseOptions(),  # result of using GetOpts::Long to parse command-line
    session => undef
};

$ENV{PERL_NET_HTTPS_SSL_SOCKET_CLASS} = "Net::SSL";    # Suppresses SSL_VERIFY_NONE
if ($context->{options}->{'ignore-ssl-errors'}) { 
    $ENV{PERL_LWP_SSL_VERIFY_HOSTNAME} = 0;            # Ignores certificate errors
}

## next line fails
$context->{session} = Vim::login(
    service_url => $context->{options}->{url}, 
    username => $context->{options}->{username}, 
    password => $context->{options}->{password}
);
```

Is there something else I (can|need to) do to get this working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got it.  I needed to reinstall Bundle::LWP from an older version, not just Net-HTTP.  Without it, I had LWP v6.05 trying to talk to Net-HTTP v6.03.

Once I realised that LWP == libwww-perl (yes, I'm *that* new), I found the overall package I needed:

```
cpan install GAAS/libwww-perl-6.03.tar.gz
```

Answer (score 0):

Reproduced with LWP 6.05 and Net::HTTP 6.01, which is the cocktail that MacPorts installs at the time of this writing. Upgrading Net::HTTP to 6.06 (current) solved it:

```
sudo cpan Net::HTTP
```